# save textfile into sd card

Tags: java, android, eclipse, save

I want to save the file to the text in the sd card, after following some tutorials I get a reference about the coding should I use. 
but after I run it does not work, just get the message "saved files failed". 
is there any of my coding wrong? 
I want to save the file came from textview in the activity.

I also add a message on the manifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

iam using this code

```
public class PreposisiRemoval extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
Button button;
Button buttonsave;
TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_preposisi_removal);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String result = intent.getStringExtra("resultFilter");

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
    tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    tv.setText(result);
    tv.setTextSize(14);

    buttonsave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
    buttonsave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            boolean mExternalStorageAvailable = false;
            boolean mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
            String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {

                mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = true;
            } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {

                mExternalStorageAvailable = true;
                mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
            } else {

                mExternalStorageAvailable = mExternalStorageWriteable = false;
            }

            try {
                File myFile = new File("/sdcard/documents/PreposisiRemoval.txt");
                myFile.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream FOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
                OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter =
                        new OutputStreamWriter(FOut);
                        myOutWriter.append(tv.getText());
                        myOutWriter.close();
                        FOut.close();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Save Files Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Save Files Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

wherein lies the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print the Exception you catch in order to see what exactly goes wrong:

```
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Save Files Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I guess there is no `documents`folder on your sdcard. Add the following line before myFile.createNewFile():

```
myFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
```

Moreover, you should not hard-code the sdcard path. Use this:

```
File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"documents/PreposisiRemoval.txt")
```

Comment: thanks sir, let me try and I will report the results

Comment: So, what is the stacktrace?

Comment: owh sorry sir that succesfull, thanks about that i make some mistakes.
I have a new problem 
how so when the store does not replace the previous file? 
because if there is a file with the same name he instantly replace 
What coding should I add?

Comment: What do you want to do instead of replacing the file?

Comment: instead, I want to create a new file 
what if there is already a file with the name PreposisiRemoval.txt new file will be saved with the name PreposisiRemoval[current time].txt how make like thats?

Answer (score 0):

As i can see you just need to write some Text into a particular file in your device storage...i would like to give a library which will handle all other things very easily.

You just have to add this library to your project and use:
    **WriteLogToFile.appendLog**  method and pass the text to it.

Go [here](http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/489299/FileLogger-rar.html) to download the library.
Its really helpful.